# React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'params' and 'posts'. You can also do a functional update 'setPosts(p => ...)

Tags: reactjs

Exactly the whole error phrase is this.

> React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'params' and
> 'posts'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. You can
> also do a functional update 'setPosts(p => ...)' if you only need
> 'posts' in the 'setPosts' call  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps   Line
> 80:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'params' and
> 'posts'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [params, setParams] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  
  const infiniteScroll = useCallback(() => {
    let scrollHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);
    let scrollTop = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop);
    let clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    if (scrollTop + clientHeight === scrollHeight && isLoading === true) {
      setIsScroll(true);
      setTimeout(function () {
        setPosts(posts.concat(posts));
        setParams((state) => state + 1);
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(params);
      }, 500);
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getTimeline(params).then((res) => {
      if(res.data.posts === '') {
        setIsScroll(false);
      }
      else if(posts === '' && res.data.posts === '') {
        setNotFound(false);
      }
      else {
        setNotFound(false);
        setPosts(res.data.posts);
        setIsLoading(true);
        setIsScroll(false);
      }
      
    }).catch((err) => {
            if(err.status === 403) {
                refreshToken();
            }
            else {
              if(err.status)
              {
                setStatusCode(err.status);
              }
              else setStatusCode("ERROR");
            }
        })
    window.addEventListener("scroll", infiniteScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", infiniteScroll);
  }, [infiniteScroll]);
```

This code is an infinite scroll function that brings a new post when the screen the user sees reaches the end of the page. However, the terminal showed a compilation error like the title. How to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `params` and `posts` on the second parameter of your `useCallback`:

```
  const infiniteScroll = useCallback(() => {
 // ...logic
  }, [isLoading, params, posts]);
```

It means that you are using those variables inside the `useCallback` function.

It is part of react `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule.

If you're using vscode I recommend installing linting stuff on your editor: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920 so it'll warn you while coding.

If you want to disable the rule you can put `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` comment before the violating line if there is a good reason.

**BUT, IT IS A BAD IDEA TO DISABLE IT.**

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for fixing the error. But does the code work fine even if I do this? Doesn't useEffect change if the things in that [] change?

Comment: yes, that's why there are cases where you wanna disable it, and sometimes you just have to make sure that those updates won't cause an issue inside the callback function (sometimes its a good thing because it recalculates everything)